# How manage columns visibility in DataGrid placed in popup part of combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a radio button and a combo box on my WPF page. The `ComboBox` is a customized version of normal `ComboBox` that can show multiple columns in the dropdown. All I want is to display or hide a certain column depending upon the `IsChecked` state of the radio button. I'm trying to use a `DataTrigger` to avoid code behind.

```
<RadioButton Content="Show ID Column" x:Name="chkScrollCustomerNumber" IsChecked="True" >

<m:MultiColumnComboBox x:Name="cboCustomer" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
ItemsSource="{Binding AllCustomers}" SelectedValuePath="customerID"             DisplayMemberPath="customerID" SelectedValue="{Binding SalesOrder.customerID}">
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colID" Binding="{Binding customerID, Mode=Default}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding customerName, Mode=Default}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding billingAddress, Mode=Default}"/>

    <m:MultiColumnComboBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chk1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="colID" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=chk1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="colID" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </m:MultiColumnComboBox.Style>
</m:MultiColumnComboBox>
```

But it tells me that colID cannot be found.

Comment: have you tried to bind DataGridTextColumn Visibility property to corresponding checkbox via similar Binding expression {Binding ElementName=chk1, Path=IsChecked} and just add BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I tried. It compiles but doesn't do anything at runtime. The ID column displays whether or not the radio button is selected.

Comment: Ok, I think the problem here is the fact that columns gets displayed in popup, and that is completely other visual tree, so it just can't get to checkboxes.

Comment: So what's the correct way out?

Comment: check my answer below, there is several available ways (as usual)

Comment: Why dont you handle it from ViewModel, Like Bind Command to RadioButton and when you check the RadioButton the Command will be fired  and in that Commands handler filter the collection binded to Itemsource accordingly.

Comment: Being a WPF newbie, I may not have understood your suggestion correctly, but ever since I have learned the "binding" method of MVVM, I'm trying to use minimum code-behind and do most of the things through some clever use of {Binding}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Ok, here is the trick how to get this thing working:

- Create VisibilityToBooleanConverter:

```cs
public class VisibilityToBoolean : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (Visibility) value == Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool) value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

- Bind IsChecked property of your RadioButton via this converter to required Column:

```xaml
<RadioButton 
    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=cboCustomer, 
             Path=Columns[0].Visibility, 
             Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}, 
             Mode=OneWayToSource}"
    ... />
```

- specify appropriate index of column for each `RadioButton`

*(All previous suggestions was wrong, because DataGridTextColumn here is not a part of logic tree, and it doesn't  have DataContext property so it useless to try and bind it's properties to anywhere)*

Comment: I like the first method, but to my wonders even that doesn't work.

Comment: after thinking about this for a while - the "simpest way" is not so simple, you will have to pass these bool properties to each of Customer object in collection...
You are saying that this doesn't work, but what exactly had you tried?

Comment: Please show xaml part of your MultiColumnComboBox template if possible, without it it's hard to tell for sure what is happening

Comment: Thanks for putting in your efforts. The MultiColumnComboBox can be seen and downloaded from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43074/WPF-Custom-ComboBox.

Comment: Answering your other question, I have added a bool property to my ViewModel and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on it and then have simply tried to bind it to my DataGridTexTColumn's Visibility using a Converter.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried using both Columns[0] approach as you mentioned, and by assigning a direct name to the column. It only works at startup, means the columns shows or gets hidden depending upon the initial value of the radio button, but remains unchanged after that.

Comment: You can't resolve column by name. But you shold be able to accesd to it by index. Maybe now the reason is in the code of combobox? I've tested my solution.

Comment: Are you using DataGrid and Column available now in framework? Have you made any changes in code of combobox there columns gets added to grid (comparing to original code from link you provided)?

Comment: It works!!! My bad. While struggling with it myself I had added 'if(columns[i].Visibility== Visibility.Visible)' in the for-loop of OnApplyTemplate(). A whole lot of thanks for taking it to the end.